# Odd permissions issues on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Macs OS 10.6/.7/.8

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, permissions, mac

*I have four macs that use a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine to share files as part of their workflow, each user has their own folder and completed jobs are dropped in an archive folder when complete. Each user has an AD account administered by a separated Domain Controller.

The mac users are having issues moving and renaming files that they created. They can create, delete and edit the files ok and sometimes they can move and rename but sometimes they can't. Any ideas?*

Edit: On further investigation, it's not permissions it's file locking. Some programs including preview or opening files (assuming locking them) and not releasing. Killing all the programs or remounting the share sees to working but it's a workaround that's not really acceptable to the users.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you propagate the permissions from the top of the share down. Take note to which folders have permission issues and investigate if the permissions are set correctly. I usually find it best to remove all parent permissions and start from scratch on a root shared folder.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, it's good advice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues in the past with OSX holding file locks open when connecting to a windows SMB share. I never really got to the root issue and we ended up using [ExtremeZ-IP](http://www.grouplogic.com/enterprise-file-sharing/mac-windows-file-sharing/) to provide AFP shares to the OSX users.

Answer (score 0):

Feels a bit cheeky answering my own question but I've spent enough time searching through boards that don't go anywhere to know how frustrating that can be.
It's not a permissions issues, I like a lot people assumed it was a permissions issue. It's file locking. The Mac opens a file that's hosted on the server and closes it, but the directory above the directory the file is contained in stays open. It's this directory that can't be moved or renamed. To close the connection you can unmount and remount the share drive, or you can kill finder, or on windows server you can Right Click on Computer, Select Manage, Expand Roles, Expand File Services, click on Share and Storage Managment. Then click Action from the menu at the top, then Manage Open Files. That will bring up a dialogue showing all the open files on the computer, I like to order by open file so I can see the file paths in order. Select the problem folder(s) and click close selected.
The latter open sounds harder but once the dialog is open it's easier to manage if you have a lot of users.

This is still not a solution, it's a workaround but I thought I could help someone else search.